# Phalcon 5.0 Camelize throws a text not found error

Tags: phalcon

I'm at Phalcon 5.0 and I am having issues calling camelize. I reached out to the community and was told that they will fix the help links that goes to 404.

Here's my issue:

```
$options['className'] = Text::camelize($options['name']);
```

is throwing error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Builder\Text' not found

Answer (score 0):

Long shot since I've never used Camelize, but in the 5.0 changelog there is a reference to Phalcon\Support\Helper\Str\Camelize.  I'm wondering if they moved where Camelize lives?

Again... total guess on my part...